# VirtualBox kept asking me to reinstall Red Hat

Tags: virtualbox, redhat

I am using Windows 10 and try to install Red Hat in virtualbox. After its installation it asked me to reboot. But after reboot I will come the install UI again. May I ask has anyone met similar problem?

I have ensured that I have disabled the Hyper-V function. And I installed Ubuntu propertly in VirtualBox two days ago.

Versions:

- Virtual box: 6.0.8-130520
- Red Hat ISO: rhel-8.0-x86_64-dvd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unbelievable, I have to mannually remove the installingt ISO in virtualbox via:

Settings-> Storage and remove the installing ISO there.